# SocketException connecting to SFTP server: name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, sftp, socketexception

I am trying to connect my sftp server using SharpSsh library, but I'm getting following error:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005):
The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found
```

I am using following code for connection

```
Tamir.SharpSsh.Sftp sftp = new Tamir.SharpSsh.Sftp("ftp.simptr.us", "username", "password");
```

Why is this exception being thrown?

Answer (score 2):

This error message is associated with the Winsock `WSANO_DATA` error code. It means, there is some problem with DNS record of the domain name you are trying to connect to.

See also
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2#WSANO_DATA

It is unlikely this is related to the SharpSsh library.

Try to telnet to verify, you should get the same error:

```
telnet ftp.simptr.us 22
```