# The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found: GET - Flurl .NET Core

Tags: api, .net-core, flurl

I wrote an .NET core API project that connects to the following URL using `Flurl` to pull the latest events for our organization:

https://webapi.legistar.com/v1/myclient/Events?$filter=EventDate+ge+datetime%272021-05-23%27&$orderby=EventDate%20desc

The code works on our development and stagings servers.  When I deploy to our production server which is in an ODMZ, I get the following error:

> Call failed. The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found: GET

Here is the `Flurl` source code for the call

```
var url = GetAllEventsPath.Replace("{Client}", configuration.ClientName);

return await configuration.BaseUrl
      .AppendPathSegment(url)
      .SetQueryParam("$filter", string.Format("EventDate+ge+datetime%27{0}%27", filterDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")), true)
      .SetQueryParam("$orderby", "EventDate%20desc", true)
      .GetJsonAsync<IEnumerable<LegistarEvent>>(cancellationToken);
```

What areas should look at to try to resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't know exactly but it appears to be a DNS issue. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16043851/62600) is the most relevant answer I could find. [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33992061/62600) suggests simply restarting the server might fix it.