# Confluence Site search with Azure Bot

Tags: azure, confluence, azure-bot-service

I am working on a requirement where I have a Bot deployed in Azure and I need to add a feature to perform a search in confluence site based on the word user types. I have written a search request using httpClient in .Net which calls Confluence search API ([https://wiki.XXXXX/ctl=siteSearch~(myword)](https://wiki.XXXXX/ctl=siteSearch%7E(myword))).

I have tested the application in my local and it is working totally fine and I am able to get search results. But I am getting the below exception when deployed to Azure.

*The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found*

Could you please help me here on why and what might be the issue. Also is there anyway I can add confluence site in Azure portal.

Answer (score 1):

Error message “The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found”, seems to be associated with the Winsock “WSANO_DATA” error code. It means, there is some issue with the DNS record of the server which you are trying to connect.

Reference Thread: [SocketException connecting to SFTP server: name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260111/socketexception-connecting-to-sftp-server-name-is-valid-but-no-data-of-the-req)

Deploying Confluence Data Center to Azure via Azure marketplace

This method uses the Azure Marketplace to deploy Confluence Data Center using our deployment templates as a reference.

**To deploy Confluence Data Center to Azure using our Marketplace app:**

1. Log in to Azure Portal.
2. Choose Create a resource to start a new deployment
3. Search for Atlassian then select Confluence Data Center from the list of Marketplace apps
4. Choose Create to start configuring the deployment
5. Follow the prompts in the wizard to configure your deployment.  Refer to the parameters table below for more information.
6. Confirm all the details are correct then click Create to purchase the subscription.

Deployment will take about 30 minutes.

Once deployment is complete, go to the Confluence URL (APPENDPOINT) listed in the deployment outputs to complete onboarding and start using Confluence.

Reference Link:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/getting-started-with-confluence-data-center-on-azure-937176452.html

https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/installing-confluence-on-windows-255362047.html